# Linkagem incorrecta em programa C e Assembly

Tags: c, assembly

Fiz uma rotina em assembler para calcular a exponencial. Compilei-a, e obtenho o ficheiro object exp.o

O programa em C++ para aproveitar esta rotina é do tipo de:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

namespace myns {
  extern "C" float exp(float x);  // para linkar com a rotina de exp.o
}

int main() {
  cout << exp(1.0) - myns::exp(1.0) << "\n";
  return (0);
}
```

Para compilar faço algo como:

```
g++ myfile.cpp exp.o -o myfile
```

E parece que a maioria das vezes a função myns::exp linka com a função exp da livraria standard do C (stdlib)... E de facto, eu preciso da C stdlib para o meu programa...

Será que se pode definir o namespace no assembler (gcc)?
Alguém sabe como forçar o link correcto, sem mudar o nome da função de exp para myexp, p.ex.? Isso implicaria mudar o assembler...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O GCC tem uma [extensão](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Asm-Labels.html) que lhe permite definir o nome do símbolo de uma variável ou função, desta forma você pode usar um nome diferente para a função porém acessar o mesmo símbolo. Basta declarar a função desta forma:

```
extern "C" float my_exp(float x) asm("exp");
```

Então no código fonte você utiliza a função como `my_exp`, porém o compilador irá usar o símbolo `exp` para esta função.

Comment: E vai linkar com a função "exp" correcta? Do ficheiro objecto my.o, e não com a "exp" da livraria standard do C?

Comment: @JDias sim, porque os símbolos são diferentes tendo em vista que C++ segue uma formatação diferente para nomear os símbolos de suas funções. Por isso o `extern "C"` é utilizado quando se está declarando o protótipo de uma função escrita em C.